# .net application icon medium size render issue on win 7

Tags: .net

I created a icon to use with my application and embedded all available sizes into the ico file.

In testing different sizes for viewing on windows server 2008 r2 I can see that all sizes render fine, including medium. However, when I push this application over to a windows 7 machine the medium size does not work. It appears as a blank page.

I read the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx#size) about dealing with Icons in .net applications and I have included all of those sizes in my ico file.

I created the file with paint.net but I doubt that should really matter.

Anyone have any ideas? This seems pretty straightforward so I don't understand where I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

recreating the icon from GIMP proved to be successful. Not sure if there is a bug with the .ico plugin in paint.net causing the issue I was having.